# How can I turn these mappings into a vim function?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

I use the following mappings to toggle relative numbers in visual mode:

```
nnoremap <silent> v v:<c-u>set nonu rnu<cr>gv
nnoremap <silent> V V0:<c-u>set nonu rnu<cr>gv
nnoremap <silent> <c-v> <c-v>:<c-u>set nonu rnu<cr>gv
vnoremap <esc> <esc>:set nornu nu<cr>
```

I would like to use the same mappings, but add a conditional check before performing the operation to exclude certain buffers types from this behavior.

I tried adding this to a function but was not successful.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] to show what you tried? Then we can point out the missing ideas

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm not sure how helpful it would be. I just wrapped `set nonu rnu<cr>gv` into a function and tried calling it. What's the problem you're having with understanding the question?

Comment: I’m not misunderstanding it, per se, but it’s often easier to say “well X doesn’t work because A and B, do Y instead” then to say “do you want Z?” In this case, you need to learn the difference between the right-hand-side of map commands (happen in the mode of the mapping) and functions (always Ex commands)—but I didn’t know that’s the issue until I saw your function body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function bodies are pure Ex, so you need (e.g.)

```
normal! v
set nonumber norelativenumber
normal! gv
```

Though note that between `:normal! v` and `:normal! gv`, the commands aren’t like the mapping where you are literally typing `:` and then have to delete the range `<C-u>` etc.

Simpler here would just be

```
set nonumber norelativenumber
normal! v
```

However, this may not leave you in visual mode! `:normal!` works better with complete commands.

As a solution, you could try and `expr` mapping and

```
return 'v'
```

Or just insert the function call between `v` and `gv` with `:<C-u>call MyFunction()<CR>`.

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble. I'll give it a shot and will report back. Much appreciated.

Comment: Works great. I posted my final solution in my original question. Cheers!

Comment: @Nathan I think it would be more appropriate if you posted that as an answer, rather than an edit of your question. There's a small drawback in the way you've implemented it, in that `V` and `Ctrl-V` will now trigger characterwise visual mode rather than linewise/blockwise... Perhaps leave the `normal! v` out of the function and run that in the mappings after the toggle command has been executed?

Comment: @filbranden sounds good. I just posted it as an answer. Would you mind showing how to  `run that in the mappings after the toggle command has been executed`. I'm not versed enough in vimscript to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I put together based on @D.BenKnoble answer (with help from @filbranden):

```
function! s:relativeLineNumbers()
  if (&filetype != 'coc-explorer')
    set nonu rnu
  endif
endfunction
command RelativeLineNumbers call s:relativeLineNumbers()
```

```
nnoremap <silent>v v:<c-u>RelativeLineNumbers<cr>gv
nnoremap <silent>V V0:<c-u>RelativeLineNumbers<cr>gv
nnoremap <silent><c-v> <c-v>:<c-u>RelativeLineNumbers<cr>gv
vnoremap <esc> <c-c>:set nornu nu<cr>
```

Note: I selected his answer rather than my own however.

Comment: Try this: `nnoremap <silent> V :ToggleRelativeLineNumbers<cr>V` and remove the `normal! v` from the function...

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Please update your answer with the settings that worked for you. I'll be happy to upvote it once you do!

Comment: Done! Cheers!!!